# including a header from a project into a static library

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a subproject (static library) inside my project.

As this static library may be used by a bunch of app, I have this config.h file on my project that contains the app configuration. The static library must read it.

The problem is that adding

```
#import "config.h"
```

on the static library fails, because the file cannot be found.

I could add an absolute path to my project root on the search headers, but I want to make this not hard coded because this static library will be used by other projects. Another problem is that I cannot use relative links like ../.., for example, because the static library is on another volume.

Including $(SRCROOT) on the search paths of the static library will give me the root for that library not for the project using it, that is what I want.

How do I solve that?

Just pay attention to my question. I am inside a static library that is used by a project. Config.h is out there in the project. I want to import that config.h on my static library.

If there is an easy way to do that, please tell me.

I have uploaded a sample project to **[here](http://dfiles.eu/files/vj7egy9ig)** and **[here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/dfvs09)**, so you can see my pain.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, somewhat of a hack, is to add a **Run Script** to each App's **Build Phase**, as the first item, and have it copy Config.h to some known place - /tmp/Config.h, and your included library will look for it there. Since the file is copied on every build, it will always be proper.

EDIT1: So not pretty, but you can add a Run Build Script to just under the Dependencies in the library. Just add one and leave the checkbox set to show environmental variables. You can see this one set:

FILE_LIST=/Volumes/Data/Users/dhoerl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-fdzaatzqtmrnzubseakedvxmsgul/Build/Intermediates/MyStaticLibrary.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyStaticLibrary.build/Objects/LinkFileList

What you can see is that several of these have as the prefix the current project folder:

/Volumes/Data/Users/dhoerl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-

You can write some script there to get the prefix, then append the local Config.h file path, and now you have a fully qualified path to the Config.h header, which you can then copy to a known location in the library. I'm going to post on the xcode forum as there may be a better solution - there use to be in Xcode 3. I'll update this if I get anything substantive back.

EDIT2: Try This:
1) Click on the library, click on Build Phases, add a Run Script Build phase by tapping bottom right '+' button

2) Drag it so its the second item in the list (below Target Dependencies)

3) Change the Shell to "/bin/ksh"

4) Paste this in, after editing it to have the proper files/paths:

```
# Get the Project Name (assumes upper/lower/numbers only in name)
PROJ=$(echo $BUILD_DIR | sed -En -e 's/(\/.*\/)([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([a-z]+\/Build\/Products)/\2/p')
# Use this variable to construct a full path
FULL_PATH="/Volumes/Data/Users/dhoerl/Downloads/nightmare/"$PROJ"/"$PROJ"/HelloWorldLayer.h"
echo FULL_PATH equals $FULL_PATH
# Make Sure MyStaticLibrary is correct
echo PROJ_DIR equals "$PROJECT_DIR/MyStaticLibrary"
cp -f "$FULL_PATH" "$PROJECT_DIR/MyStaticLibrary"
```

5) This assumes that you put the library anywhere you want, but each App project has to havethe same parent folder (not much of a restriction - what I did in the past).

PS: When I do this kind of thing, I usually don't include an actual file of the app, but create a header for a class that is not instantiated in the library. Lets call this Foo. So in your library, you have Foo.h, and it has lots of methods that return info - the number of widgets, the location of some special folder, plists, arrays, dictionaries, whatever. The idea is the library knows how to get whatever it needs through this interface (class singleton, or just a class with class methods. YMMV.

PSS: anyone else reading this, it pays to create demo projects.

Comment: not working for me. I have uploaded a sample project to **[here](http://dfiles.eu/files/vj7egy9ig)** and **[here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/dfvs09)**, so you can see my pain.

Comment: ok, I understood it in principle but I don't have a clue how to fix that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Uh, well forget the note. I told you how to move the config - in the script file that runs in the library, just before the library code compiles. Is it not clear? do you really need me to write the script file too? If you go to my profile you will find how to contact me directly via email, we can avoid more comments...

Comment: I will not take more of your time. Thanks for the huge effort. I appreciate that. I will try to decipher this puzzle.

Comment: Look, its not a huge effort and that's why lots of us try to help. The script isn't that hard - you can probably just grab the string from the '/' to the first '-', then  append "/headers/Config.h" to it. Now you have the fully qualified path to the App Config.h. Add a final line: "cp "/..../Config.h" $(PROJECT_DIR)/pathToIncludesInLibrary". This is going to be no more than a 6 line script.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go a different route. Make this config.h file part of the static library using compiler symbols in it to switch features. Then in your projects define those symbols depending on what features you need.

Comment: I cannot do that because config.h is specific to each project. If I modify config.h for every project and it is inside the static library, all projects will read that modified version.

Comment: not working for me. I have uploaded a sample project to **[here](http://dfiles.eu/files/vj7egy9ig)** and **[here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/dfvs09)**, so you can see my pain.